# google script for inserting a row and copying formulas down

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new here and struggling with the wonderful world of google script at the mo so could realy do with your help.

I have a google sheets doc and columns c to z all contain formulas that I have copied down the whole sheet,

the problem is I need to be able to insert a row and have the formula in the row above it copy down.
I found a code online that will add a new last row and copy the formulas but I need one that I can select a row, click the script and it insert a new rowwith the formulas copied down,

can anyone give me help on the script I need to do this?

here is the script I have which does exactly what I want but for the last row not the selected row.

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name:"Add New Last Row", functionName:"addRow"}];
  ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
}

function addRow() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

if someone can tel me how to fix this I would be very greatful

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 1):

## Code:

Instead of `sh.getLastRow()` use `sh.getActiveCell().getRow()`

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your script since it has a few variables without being properly declared.

```html
function addaRow() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lRow = sh.getActiveCell().getRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
  var range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```